# How to create a table from the attributes of another table that contain a key word?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL table called SCUBA_CLASSES with attributes ID and NAME. In the table are different kinds of scuba diving classes from beginner to advanced levels. There is a second table called REQUIRED_BOOKS that has the attributes ID and TITLE that contain all the books required by different scuba classes.

I'd like to create a new table called INTRO_REQUIREMENTS with an attribute ID. It will contain a list of all the books required by scuba classes whose name starts with the word "Introduction". How would you create this?

So far I have:

```
CREATE TABLE INTRO_REQUIREMENTS AS
SELECT SCUBA_CLASSES.ID
FROM SCUBA_CLASSES, REQUIRED_BOOKS
WHERE SCUBA_CLASSES.ID = REQUIRED_BOOKS.ID;
```

I can generate a list of classes with required books but can't figure out how to add the requirement that the name of the class has to start with "Introduction".

Comment: `WHERE name LIKE "introduction%"`

Comment: Thanks! Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

add one more condition in where clause using using AND and Search name using [LIKE](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php).

```
CREATE TABLE INTRO_REQUIREMENTS AS
SELECT SCUBA_CLASSES.ID
FROM SCUBA_CLASSES, REQUIRED_BOOKS
WHERE SCUBA_CLASSES.ID = REQUIRED_BOOKS.ID
AND name LIKE "introduction%";
```